# make json to pojo from an array without index

Tags: android, json, retrofit, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

I'm using retrofit and I have a contact class like this :

```
public class MyContact {

    private String response;
    private String message;

    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

and there is a part of my json :

```
{"Response":"Success","Message":"YES","Data":{"Info":{"id":"1" , "name":"leon"}}}
```

**I'm using retrofit to get this `JSON`**

The question is how to manage it by pojo in android.I
I don't want to get 'Data' part just 'response' and 'message'

My retrofit part of the app is completely nice and running

Comment: You need to do JSON parsing to extract only relevant fields refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: im using retrofit to get this json @AkshayKatariya

Comment: you can try this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it takes json string as input and will give you model class

Comment: help me solve it @Fred

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do JSON Parsing like this

```
String res = "{\"Response\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"YES\",\"Data\":{\"Info\":{\"id\":\"1\" , \"name\":\"leon\"}}}";

MyContact model =new MyContact();

if (res!=null);//Retrofit response 
    try
    {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(res);
        model.setResponse(jo.optString("Response"));
        model.setMessage(jo.optString("Message"));

        Log.d("Akshay","Response = "+model.getResponse() + " " +model.getMessage());
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: after request from retrofit method of onFailure is giving back to me . i have no response in there

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your Retrofit code, you should get this JSON from server inside `onResponse `

Answer (score 1):

**Create the Serializable class -**

```
class Response implements Serializable{
    @SerializedName("Response")
    private String response;
    @SerializedName("Message")
    private String message;

    public Response(){}

    public Response(String response, String message){
        this.message = message;
        this.response = response;
    }

    //todo getter and setter methods
}
```

**Now parse the JSON data with help of Gson.**

```
String jsonString = "{\"Response\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"YES\",\"Data\":{\"Info\":{\"id\":\"1\" , \"name":\"leon\"}}}";
Response responseObject = new Gson()
                          .fromJson(
                             jsonString,
                             Response.class
                          );
```

in this POJO class above you can add other data if you want. for avoiding any specific property to serialize and deserialize you can use ***exclusion strategy***.

For more information on this yoou can go [here](http://aideafactory.com/json-serialization-and-deserialization-with-gson/).

Comment: Your answer is good but there might be a case where you need those fields from model POJO to set value in them and use as `Parcelable `

Comment: i dont get it @AkshayKatariya. can you explain a bit more.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya for your question just need to implements Serializable to Response.Class .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid any data used below keyword 
**transient**

and according to given above json pojo class will be like this..

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("Info")
private Info info;

public Info getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(Info info) {
    this.info = info;
}
```

}

```
public class Info {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

then finaly response pojo class..

```
public class ResponseData {

@SerializedName("Response")
private String response;
@SerializedName("Message")
private String message;
@SerializedName("Data")
transient 
private Data data;

public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(String response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}