# How to parse Json using Retrofit if key is inside of another object

Tags: android, retrofit, jsonparser

Can anyone help me in parsing below json using retrofit?

```
{
  "key1": "value",
  "key2": {
           "key3": "value2",
           "key4": "some random text is here"
          },
  "value2" : {
               -- actual data is here ---
             }
}
```

here "value2" will change. i'm not able to figure how to get the value of "Key3" and get the actual data using Retrofit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use custom JSON parsing refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014049/4762767

Answer (score 2):

you can json data into pojo class put in your json data in below website it generate pojo class..

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

add below dependency into app level gradle file ..

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

then after when you make retrofit object pass this line ..

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, lets say you have JSONObject with above mentioned json.

You can parse it like `String value = jsonObject.optString("key1");`

Answer (score -1):

Retrofit supports converterFactory, you can try Gson or Jackson with it

Find an example below

Add dependency in gradle,

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Java Code

```
 new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL).
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
            client(okHttpClient).
            build();

 public interface GetAllAPI {
        @GET("/all")
        List<Country> getCountries();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("Your_json_string");
        String key1 = jsonObject.optString("key1");
        JSONObject key2 = jsonObject.optJSONObject("key2");

        String value2 = key2.optString("key3");//It will get value

        JSONObject jsonObjectValue2 = jsonObject.optJSONObject(value2);// now use value2 here for actual result
        String finalValue = jsonObjectValue2.optString("next_value");
        //....and so on

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```